# Does a multi-line statement affects Python interpreter performance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

Consider these two same function calls:

```
func(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

and

```
func(
    arg1,
    arg2,
    ...
)
```

Does a single line statement performs better than a multi-line one?

Comment: No, it shouldn't make any difference. The script is first compiled to byte code, that's what gets executed.

Answer (score 3):

No. Both produce the same abstract syntax tree (AST) from which the Python byte code is produced. Only the parser ever sees a difference between the two.

(And yes, I am intentionally ignoring the time it takes the parser to iterate through the extra whitespace in the second example as negligible.)